# If $\langle x,y \rangle=\|x\|\|y\|$ then $y=0$ or $x=\alpha y$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Let X be a (complex) inner product space.
> Proof that if for some $x,y \in X$ we have  $\langle x,y \rangle=\|x\|\|y\|$ then $y=0$ or there exists complex $\alpha$ such that $x=\alpha y$

I have tried to proof it using different properties of inner product but that led me nowhere. I appreciate any hints how to solve it.

Comment: There are two cases: $x = \alpha y$ or $x = \alpha y + \beta z$ with $\langle y, z \rangle = 0$ (why?). Show that in the first case we get equality. In the second case, substitute the expression for $x$ and expand using linearity. What do you notice?

Comment: Find the minimum of the function $f(\alpha) = \langle x - \alpha y,x - \alpha y \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $y=0$, then we are done.

Case 2: let $y \ne 0$ and put $ \alpha = \frac{||x||}{||y||}$ and compute $||x-\alpha y||^2$ with the inner product ( $||z||^2=\langle z,z \rangle$). See what happens !

Comment: Which also reveals that $\alpha$ is real.